# jquery issues with fancybox code

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using the following code to trigger fancybox functionality

```
$.fancybox({
        fitToView   : true,
        type        :'iframe',
        href        : shref,
        width       : swidth,
        height      : sheight,
        scrolling   : 'no',
        modal       : true,
        iframe  : {'scrolling': 'no'},
        helpers : {
          overlay : {
            css : { 'overflow' : 'hidden' }
          }
        },
        beforeClose: function() {
            alert("now close");
            $(".loadscript").load(surl + '.loadscript');
        }
    });
```

now when i close the button on my iframed fancybox using `parent.$.fancybox.close();`

fancybox closes and i get an alert, but it throws an error when it tries to reoad the file in the parent div

error i am getting in firefox:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://website.com/secure/undefined.loadscript

Comment: `undefined.loadscript` is a strong indication that the `surl` variable doesn't exist (= is undefined.)

Comment: you beat it, how i accept your answer

Comment: No problem, go ahead and accept Annarfych's answer if it works for you.